# Error al actualizar textmaker en Ubuntu

Tags: linux

Quiero actualizar `Texmaker` a través de un paquete .deb.

He usado `sudo dpkg -i archivo.deb`, pero me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, pon lo que está en la imagen _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Puedes forzar el reemplazo de los recursos por los que se está quejando, usando la opción `--force-overwrite`:

```
sudo dpkg --install --force-overwrite texmaker_5.1.3_ubuntu_20.04_amd64.deb
```